# Pentaho report designer split query result in two or three tables

Tags: report, pentaho, designer

I need some help with the next question:
I have a select that I want to show but the result is shown in several pages because the select contains over 100 rows. 
I want to show two or three tables in the same page with these 100 rows but I don't know how to do it

I appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to increase the number of rows per page so that all your records will be shown in one page?

Comment: I want to display the result of one table in two tables o mores depending the amount of rows in the same page. What I have now is that the result of one query returns one table in many pages, but I want this in one page. I can't post images yet because I don't have the necesary reputation points to do it, but here are the images: I have this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxol6-3_xGbsM2NMcGk5SkxncTg/view?usp=sharing    but I want this:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxol6-3_xGbsZmkyOHVSRV9CMDg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature exists as such in Pentaho Report Designer.
JIRA new feature ticket is there whose status is still

> Unresolved

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-2107

According to the ticket it has been moved to Backlog to be developed in Version 6.0.0